# In SQLAlchemy, is there a way to eager-load multiple aliased selectables of the same class using one query?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy mapped class `MyClass`, and two aliases for it. I can eager-load a relationship `MyClass.relationship` on each alias separately using `selectinload()` like so:

```
alias_1, alias_2 = aliased(MyClass), aliased(MyClass)
q = session.query(alias_1, alias_2).options(
    selectinload(alias_1.relationship),
    selectinload(alias_2.relationship))
```

However, this results in 2 separate SQL queries on `MyClass.relationship` (in addition to the main query on `MyClass`, but this is irrelevant to the question). Since these 2 queries on `MyClass.relationship` are to the same table, I think that it should be possible to merge the primary keys generated within the `IN` clause in these queries, and just run 1 query on `MyClass.relationship`.

My best guess for how to do this is:

```
alias_1, alias_2 = aliased(MyClass), aliased(MyClass)
q = session.query(alias_1, alias_2).options(
    selectinload(MyClass.relationship))
```

But it clearly didn't work:

> `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapped attribute "MyClass.relationship" does not apply to any of the root entities in this query, e.g. aliased(MyClass), aliased(MyClass). Please specify the full path from one of the root entities to the target attribute.`

Is there a way to do this in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 2):

So, this is exactly the same issue we had. This [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance_loading.html#polymorphic-selectin-loading) explains how to do it.

You need to add `selectin_polymorphic`. For anyone else if you are using `with_polymorphic` in your `select` then remove it.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import selectin_polymorphic

query = session.query(MyClass).options(
    selectin_polymorphic(MyClass, [alias_1, alias_2]),
    selectinload(MyClass.relationship)

)
```